# How would I compare two Lists(Of <CustomClass>) in VB?

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm working on implementing the equality operator `=` for a custom class of mine.  The class has one property, `Value`, which is itself a `List(Of OtherClass)`, where `OtherClass` is yet another custom class in my project.

I've already implemented the `IComparer`, `IComparable`, `IEqualityComparer`, and `IEquatable` interfaces, the operators `=`, `<>`, `bool` and `not`, and overriden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `OtherClass`.  This should give me all the tools I need to compare these objects, and various tests comparing two singular instances of these objects so far checks out.

However, I'm not sure how to approach this when they are in a `List`.  I don't care about the list order.  Given:

```
Dim x As New List(Of OtherClass) From
    {New OtherClass("foo"),
     New OtherClass("bar"),
     New OtherClass("baz")}

Dim y As New List(Of OtherClass) From
    {New OtherClass("baz"),
     New OtherClass("foo"),
     New OtherClass("bar")}
```

Then `(x = y).ToString` should print out `True`.

I need to compare the same (not distinct) set of objects in this list.  The list shouldn't support dupes of `OtherClass`, but I'll have to figure out how to add that in later as an exception.  Not interested in using LINQ.  It looks nice, but in the few examples I've played with, adds a performance overhead in that bugs me.  Loops are ugly, but they are fast :)

A straight code answer is fine, but I'd like to understand the logic needed for such a comparison as well.  I'm probably going to have to implement said logic more than a few times down the road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example should return false. List<> is ordered collection, and if X contains foo,bar,baz, it is not the same as baz,foo,bar. You are not supposed to change this kind of expected behavior! What you describe is a set or bag, not a list. Bag is similar to list, but doesn't care about the order of items. Then it would obviously return true in your example.

Edit for clarity: List<> is ordered by indices of items, not their values. And this important property of this kind of collection affects its behavior and speed in all operations.

OK, forget about it, and let's say you just want to test it as you defined. The fastest universally-applicable algorithm will be O(n*log2n) if you sort the contents and then compare.

Options:

1. You can sort both lists to two temp collections, then simply compare their items.
2. You can sort X to a temp collection, and then sequentially go thru Y and try to find each item of Y in X and remove it. In the end you can see if temp is empty, then X and Y are the same.
3. If you often compare for equality and not so often insert new items, you can create some new "smart" List, which will sort items on insertion. It will consist of a real List<> and some kind of sorted collection inside.

**Rough analysis of complexity:**

Options 1. and 2. are O(n) on insertion of n items, and O(n*log2n) on comparison of two lists.

Option 3. is O(n*log2n) on insertion of n items, and O(n) on comparison of two lists.

If you want to get under O(n*log2n), you probably have to go to a different collection than List<>. If you use class HashSet instead (present since .NET 3.5), you can probably get a much faster result. But I haven't tried it in praxis. HashSet is an implementation of unordered collection aka set/bag. It doesn't support comparison of two hashsets, but you can do this on your own this way:

Use foreach to iterate thru items of X and try to find each item in Y.

```
if(X.Count != Y.Count) return false;
foreach(var i in X) {
  if(Y.Contains(i)==false) return false;
}
return true;
```

This code is very slow on lists, it's O(n^2). But it should be quite fast on HashSets, O(n). If you don't encounter any more hidden problems, this should fly like a rocket!

In praxis, if you need to stay with List<> and want the speed of HashSet<>, you can rewrite just one of your collection (either X or Y) to a new class which will contain two collections inside - a List<> and a HashSet<> - and will store all items to both of them.

You can also use a classic Dictionary<>, HashTable or some other classic collection of .NET to implement the same thing. They will run faster than comparing two Lists, but probably need more memory and not be as fast as HashSets.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `List(Of T)` was an ordered collection.  I thought it was intended as a strongly-typed collection intended to replace `ArrayList` when you know that the array/collection will only ever be of one type.  Implementing a sub-class that does both a List and a HashSet seems too much.  The output of the class will be a comma-separated set of string values (these are what are stored in the List), and an external program that uses these strings doesn't care about the order.

Comment: List<> and ArrayList are both ordered. (They are like an array, and array is ordered.) If HashSet seems too much for you, use sorting. (List<>.Clone() as List<>).Sort(), then compare items.

Comment: Never really got into math algorithms back in school, so "O(n*log2n)" doesn't mean much to me.  However, if I need to start using unordered collections, and a HashSet is faster, then I'll have to look into switching to that (I'm always up for performance things).  Though, doesn't a HashSet incur penalties when you start to get above 10 items?  I believe this is what the `HybridDictionary` class is for.

Comment: @Aleš: Ah, well, is the ordering aspect really that important when the List is just being used by my custom class for internal storage and is never really exposed outside of the class in its raw form?

Comment: Basic comparison of lits is O(n^2) whic is very slow. Usually O(n*log2n) is fast enough, but if you have millions of items, it can get slow too. O(n) is much better. :-)

Comment: Items in List are ordered by indices, not by values. This is maybe why you though it is and unordered collection. But you need to order items by values in order to know whether items in two collections are the same. As I wrote earlier, what solution will be fastest depends on how do you use it. Whether you often insert items and not so often compare whole collections, or if you often compare and not so often insert.

Comment: I haven't reach the point of development yet to know exactly how often items will be inserted or removed, but I know comparison will be needed a bit.  In theory, anyways.  The ordering by indices is something I've used a bit with Lists (I saw List as a better Array, basically), but I never gave thought to their ordering.  My CompareTo implementation takes care of ordering by value versus index.  If I used a HashSet, is the ability to compare the set of items different or quicker/slower?

Comment: This is described in my first post, the "answer". HashSet provides fast search for item in O(1). So you can iterate using foreach on one HashSet and look if each of its items is present in the other HashSet. This is fast. If both HashSets have the same number of items, the sets are the same. In addition, if HashSet uses some predictable algorithm of storing items (which is possible, but not neccessary), both collections are in fact ordered by hash, so you can double-iterate thru two collections at once.

Comment: Ah! I thought the comparison snippet you provided was for Lists.  I implemented that and then stepped through the resulting code, and it maps all the way out to my custom `CompareTo` and `op_Equality` functions/operators in the sub-classes, so the result is actually pretty fast.  I'll have to make a copy of the class code and swap lists for hashsets to get an idea on if they offer me a good speed benefit.  Forgive me if I seem a bit daft on this...I came from VB6 where all I had was a plain-old Collection.  I've also been learning .NET as I go along.

Comment: It looks like I can partially cheat here.  I tested a copy of my classes out using HashSet<T> instead of List<T>, and looping it 100,000 times added too much performance ovehread during the initialization.  However, the comparison was blazing fast in `op_Equality`.  So I will keep List<T> for the primary storage, and during comparison, initialize a new HashSet<T>, then use the comparison loop in your answer.

Comment: Result?  Testing with plain List<T> 100,000 times on my system takes about ~66,000ms (66sec, or 1min 6 sec).  Copying to a HashSet<T> in `op_Equality` adds negligible overhead and cuts the comparison time down to a whopping ~6700ms, or 6.7sec.  That's a massive, massive speed improvement!

Answer (score -1):

Ok it was my misunderstanding of .IndexOf() - it just finds first item in the list with text that is specified in ()

So it must be like this to work correctly as I wanted to:

```
    Dim indexOfMyItem As Integer = -1

    For Each i In CompList1
        indexOfMyItem = indexOfMyItem + 1
        If CompList2.Contains(i) Then
            If Not test.ListBox1.Items.Contains(indexOfMyItem) Then
                test.ListBox1.Items.Add(indexOfMyItem)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```